# Unable to access tables created with Python program using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have created some tables using python script using sqlalchemy in the DB postgres.
when I log into db using shell for that uname:password combination and execute command to show tables
\dt 
it gives me following output

```
 Schema |       Name       | Type  |     Owner      
--------+------------------+-------+----------------
 public | CLASS_DESCRIPTOR | table | prefix_manager
 public | test             | table | prefix_manager
 public | user             | table | prefix_manager
 public | user_prefs       | table | prefix_manager
(6 rows)
```

The tables test was created using normal python script, and user,user_prefs were created using simple sqlalchemy code given below,

```
from sqlalchemy import *
engine = create_engine('postgresql://prefix_manager:password1@localhost:5432/prefix_manager')

metadata = MetaData()

user = Table('user', metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key = True),
    Column('user_name', String(16), nullable = False),
    Column('email_address', String(60), key='email'),
    Column('password', String(20), nullable = False)
)

user_prefs = Table('user_prefs', metadata,
    Column('pref_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey("user.user_id"), nullable=False),
    Column('pref_name', String(40), nullable=False),
    Column('pref_value', String(100))
)
```

metadata.create_all(engine)

But the table `CLASS_DESCRIPTOR` was created by another python script with sqlalchemy.
So when I do `SELECT * from CLASS_DESCRIPTOR` 
it gives me following error

```
ERROR:  relation "class_descriptor" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

postgresql distinguishes case in identifiers when they are specified using double quotes, as in

```
create table "FOO" (...);
```

but normalizes case (to all lowercase) when quotes are not present;  in order to use that table, you must give postgresql a correctly cased (and therefore quoted) identifier.  that is:

```
select * from "CLASS_DESCRIPTOR"
```

Comment: Spot on. Because of PostgreSQL's case conventions, I find that it's easier to use all lowercase names or `names_like_this` with PostgreSQL.

Comment: you can use whatever casing you like, so long as you skip the quotes, its the quotes that do surprising things, not the casing in general.

Comment: Certainly, but PG's own management tools (like pgadmin) show unquoted names in all lowercase regardless of how you specify them in your code. If you want to easily distinguish words within long names in pgadmin, underscores are an easy way to do it.

Comment: Bang on.. Working properly.